# How does the key get set for the UltraGridBand?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, infragistics, ultrawingrid

How does the [Key preoperty](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~Key.html) get set on an [UltraGrid](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.html) when calling [SetDataBinding(object DataSource, string DataMember, bool hideNewColumns)](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~SetDataBinding%28Object,String,Boolean%29.html)? And How can I set it to something besides `List'1`?

I have the following form and class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ultraGrid2.SetDataBinding(new List<row>(), string.Empty, true);
        this.ultraGrid2.DisplayLayout.ColumnChooserEnabled = DefaultableBoolean.True; 
        // breakpoint on the above line and run the below immediate window code
    }
}

public class row
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

After setting the data binding, the below code always gives me `List'1` in the immediate window:

```
this.ultraGrid2.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Key
```

Comment: Why did I think this was a music question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the UltraGridBand object there is a private method that gets called during data binding called InitBandKey and it is within this method that the key is being set.

The logic for this is similar to the following:

```
CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)this.bindingManager;
if (cm.List is ITypedList) 
{
    newKey = ((ITypedList)cm.List).GetListName(null);
} 
else 
{
  newKey = cm.List.GetType().Name;
}
```

In your example, you are getting the result of `(new List<row>()).GetType().Name`

You could define a class that derives from `List<row>` and then the name of that class would be the key of the band.  For example:

```
public class CustomList:List<row>
{

}
```

And then the updated call to SetDataBinding for this example is:

```
this.ultraGrid1.SetDataBinding(new CustomList(), string.Empty, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `Key` of the `Band[0]` at design time.

Usually the Band[x].Key is the name of the DataTable/DataView that is binded, but in case of `List<T>` there is no name to use and perhaps this is automatically defined by the control

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me a NotSupportedException stating "Band key can not be set."

Comment: Strange, just tried now on an empty UltraWinGrid in a WinForms solution and I can set that property.

Comment: I still get that error. The documentation seems to make it sound like it can, but should not be used [Key Property](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand~Key.html).